# Unblock Me / Rush Hour solver

Tags: algorithm, f#

This is my first complete program written in F# (I was from C# and occasionally do interop) and I believe there are quite a few places I didn't tackle well in terms of coding practice.

Unblock Me / Rush Hour:

```
    5   b   b       k   j   
    4   c   c   c   k   j   
    3   a   a       k   i   l
    2   d       g   g   i   l
    1   d       f   h   h   l
    0   e   e   f           
        0   1   2   3   4   5
```

A player can move horizontal bricks horizontally, vertical bricks vertically. The aim is to move the brick denoted by `aa` to the rightmost.

I used depth limited search to solve this problem, and the full running code is attached. It is slow (depth 7 takes 2 sec), and I know there are better algorithms for the problem.

However, my objective is to learn F# well, so could someone please shed some light on me how to improve the code without making to much tweaks on the algorithm itself?

```
module Unblock
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics


type Position = int * int // (RowID, ColumnID)

type Brick = char * int // (Name, Length)

type State = Position[]
type BrickInfo = Brick[]

type Direction = 
    | Up
    | Down
    | Left
    | Right

    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        | Up -> "Up"
        | Down -> "Down"
        | Left -> "Left"
        | Right -> "Right"

type Move = int * Direction

//module myFunction =

let checkBoth target length current =
    if current > target || current + length - 1 < target then true else false



let test (initialState: State) (brickInfo: Brick[]) (horizontalBricks: int[][], verticalBricks: int[][]) (rowNum, columnNum) =
    //let sw = new StreamWriter("output.csv");
    let (redRowNum, _) = initialState.[0]
    let (_, redLength) = brickInfo.[0]
    let mySet = new HashSet<_>(HashIdentity.Structural)

    let horizontalBricksAll = horizontalBricks |> Array.concat
    let verticalBricksAll = verticalBricks |> Array.concat

    let rec solveDFS (currentState: State) (lastBrick, lastDirection) depth =

        let generateState i (newPosition: Position) =
            let nextState = currentState |> Array.copy
            nextState.[i] <- newPosition
            nextState

        let isDuplicated (set: HashSet<_>) =
            if set.Contains (currentState) then true
            else
                //let f = currentState |> Array.map (fun elem -> sw.Write("{0},{1} ", fst elem, snd elem))
                //sw.WriteLine()
                ignore (set.Add currentState)
                false

        let checkVacancy (rowID, columnID) =         
            let checkHorizontal i = 
                let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
                let (_, startColumn) = currentState.[i]
                checkBoth columnID length startColumn
            let checkVertical i =
                let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
                let (startRow, _) = currentState.[i]
                checkBoth rowID length startRow
            (horizontalBricks.[rowID] |> Array.forall checkHorizontal) && (verticalBricks.[columnID] |> Array.forall checkVertical)

        let generateRight i =
            let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if columnID + length >= columnNum then None
            else Some ((rowID, columnID + length), (rowID, columnID + 1))
        let generateLeft i =
            let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if columnID = 0 then None
            else Some ((rowID, columnID - 1), (rowID, columnID - 1))
        let generateUp i =
            let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if rowID + length >= rowNum then None
            else Some ((rowID + length, columnID), (rowID + 1, columnID))
        let generateDown i =
            let (_, length) = brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if rowID = 0 then None
            else Some ((rowID - 1, columnID), (rowID - 1, columnID))

        if depth < 7
            && not (isDuplicated mySet)
            &&
             (
                let (_, columnLeft) = currentState.[0]
                [|columnLeft + redLength .. columnNum - 1|] |> Array.forall (fun columnID -> checkVacancy (redRowNum, columnID))
                ||
                horizontalBricksAll |> Seq.tryFind (fun elem ->
                                                        (match generateRight elem with                              
                                                         | Some (a,b) when checkVacancy a -> solveDFS (generateState elem b) (elem, Right) (depth + 1)
                                                         | _ -> false)
                                                        ||
                                                        (match generateLeft elem with
                                                         | Some (a,b) when checkVacancy a -> solveDFS (generateState elem b) (elem, Left) (depth + 1)
                                                         | _ -> false)
                                                    )
                                    |> Option.isSome
                ||
                verticalBricksAll |> Seq.tryFind (fun elem ->
                                                        (match generateUp elem with                              
                                                         | Some (a,b) when checkVacancy a -> solveDFS (generateState elem b) (elem, Up) (depth + 1)
                                                         | _ -> false)
                                                        ||
                                                        (match generateDown elem with
                                                         | Some (a,b) when checkVacancy a -> solveDFS (generateState elem b) (elem, Down) (depth + 1)
                                                         | _ -> false)
                                                 )
                                    |> Option.isSome
             )
             then 
                 Console.WriteLine("Brick Name {0} Direction {1}", fst brickInfo.[lastBrick], lastDirection)
                 true
             else 
                ignore (mySet.Remove(currentState))
                false
    Console.WriteLine (solveDFS initialState (0, Right) 0) // the output would have an additional line of useless information (0, Right)



let x0 = ('a',2)
let x1 = ('b',2)
let x2 = ('c',3)
let x3 = ('d',2)
let x4 = ('e',2)
let x5 = ('f',1)
let x6 = ('g',2)
let x7 = ('h',2)
let x8 = ('i',2)
let x9 = ('j',2)
let x10 = ('k',3)
let x11 = ('l',3)

let brickInfo = [|x0;x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6;x7;x8;x9;x10;x11|]
let horizontalBricks = [|[|4|];[|7|];[|6|];[|0|];[|2|];[|1|]|]
let verticalBricks = [|[|3|];[||];[|5|];[|10|];[|8;9|];[|11|]|]
let rowNum = 6
let columnNum = 6

let p0 = (3,0)
let p1 = (5,0)
let p2 = (4,0)
let p3 = (1,0)
let p4 = (0,0)
let p5 = (0,2)
let p6 = (2,2)
let p7 = (1,3)
let p8 = (2,4)
let p9 = (4,4)
let p10 = (3,3)
let p11 = (1,5)


let initialState =[|p0;p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11|]

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    let sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()

    ignore (test (initialState) (brickInfo) (horizontalBricks, verticalBricks) (rowNum, columnNum))
    sw.Stop()

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some places you could tweak the code to squeeze out more performance and/or adhere to better F# style.

---

If you're not going to use a function in curried form -- i.e., you're always going to pass all of the arguments at once -- it's better to define the function as such. Doing so allows the F# compiler to compile the function into a single .NET method, rather than a bunch of closures.

For example, change this:

```
let rec solveDFS (currentState: State) (lastBrick, lastDirection) depth =
```

to this:

```
let rec solveDFS (currentState : State, lastBrick, lastDirection, depth) =
```

I don't think this'll make much of a difference for your code, but it will make a difference for larger codebases.

---

`inline` the `generateRight`, etc. functions -- they're fairly small and only used once so it'd be better to avoid the overhead of a function call.

---

When your input is an array, it's better to use functions in the `Array` module instead of the `Seq` module, because the `Array` functions are optimized for arrays. So, change the `Seq.tryFind` calls to `Array.tryFind`.

---

If you can, it'd be better to use 2d arrays (`[,]`) instead of jagged arrays (`[][]`). The reason is that a 2d array is stored as a contiguous block of memory and only requires a few more arithmetic operations to access than a 1d array, whereas a jagged array is stored in non-contiguous chunks so you have an additional indirection and poor memory locality (i.e., doesn't work as well with the CPU cache).

I didn't make this change to the code I posted below, but this could provide a noticeable improvement in your code since you're frequently accessing the arrays.

Note that there is an `Array2D` module for working with 2d arrays.

---

Here's your code with the changes I described, other than the modification for 2d arrays:

```
module Unblock
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics


type Position = int * int // (RowID, ColumnID)

type Brick = char * int // (Name, Length)

type State = Position[]
type BrickInfo = Brick[]

type Direction = 
    | Up
    | Down
    | Left
    | Right

    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        | Up -> "Up"
        | Down -> "Down"
        | Left -> "Left"
        | Right -> "Right"

type Move = int * Direction

//module myFunction =

let inline checkBoth target length current =
    if current > target || current + length - 1 < target then true else false



let test (initialState: State, brickInfo: Brick[], horizontalBricks: int[][], verticalBricks: int[][], rowNum, columnNum) =
    //let sw = new StreamWriter("output.csv");
    let (redRowNum, _) = initialState.[0]
    let (_, redLength) = brickInfo.[0]
    let mySet = HashSet<_> (HashIdentity.Structural)

    let horizontalBricksAll = Array.concat horizontalBricks
    let verticalBricksAll = Array.concat verticalBricks

    let rec solveDFS (currentState: State, lastBrick, lastDirection, depth) =

        let generateState i (newPosition: Position) =
            let nextState = Array.copy currentState
            nextState.[i] <- newPosition
            nextState

        let inline isDuplicated (set: HashSet<_>) =
            if set.Contains (currentState) then true
            else
                //let f = currentState |> Array.map (fun elem -> sw.Write("{0},{1} ", fst elem, snd elem))
                //sw.WriteLine()
                ignore (set.Add currentState)
                false

        let checkVacancy (rowID, columnID) =
            horizontalBricks.[rowID]
            |> Array.forall (fun i ->
                let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
                let startColumn = snd currentState.[i]
                checkBoth columnID length startColumn)

            && verticalBricks.[columnID]
            |> Array.forall (fun i ->
                let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
                let startRow = fst currentState.[i]
                checkBoth rowID length startRow)

        let inline generateRight i =
            let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if columnID + length >= columnNum then None
            else Some ((rowID, columnID + length), (rowID, columnID + 1))
        let inline generateLeft i =
            let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if columnID = 0 then None
            else Some ((rowID, columnID - 1), (rowID, columnID - 1))
        let inline generateUp i =
            let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if rowID + length >= rowNum then None
            else Some ((rowID + length, columnID), (rowID + 1, columnID))
        let inline generateDown i =
            let length = snd brickInfo.[i]
            let (rowID, columnID) = currentState.[i]
            if rowID = 0 then None
            else Some ((rowID - 1, columnID), (rowID - 1, columnID))

        // This was refactored from inside the condition of the 'if' statement below.
        // It's marked as 'inline', so it should compile to the exact same IL, but it's
        // much easier to read this way.
        let inline check () =
            let columnLeft = snd currentState.[0]
            [|columnLeft + redLength .. columnNum - 1|]
            |> Array.forall (fun columnID ->
                checkVacancy (redRowNum, columnID))
            ||
            horizontalBricksAll
            |> Array.tryFind (fun elem ->
                (match generateRight elem with
                    | Some (a, b) when checkVacancy a ->
                        solveDFS (generateState elem b, elem, Right, depth + 1)
                    | _ -> false)
                ||
                (match generateLeft elem with
                    | Some (a, b) when checkVacancy a ->
                        solveDFS (generateState elem b, elem, Left, depth + 1)
                    | _ -> false))
                |> Option.isSome
            ||
            verticalBricksAll
            |> Array.tryFind (fun elem ->
                (match generateUp elem with
                    | Some (a, b) when checkVacancy a ->
                        solveDFS (generateState elem b, elem, Up, depth + 1)
                    | _ -> false)
                ||
                (match generateDown elem with
                    | Some (a, b) when checkVacancy a ->
                        solveDFS (generateState elem b, elem, Down, depth + 1)
                    | _ -> false))
            |> Option.isSome

        if depth < 7 && not (isDuplicated mySet) && check () then
            printfn "Brick Name %c Direction %A" (fst brickInfo.[lastBrick]) lastDirection
            true
        else
            mySet.Remove currentState
            |> ignore
            false

    // the output would have an additional line of useless information (0, Right)
    Console.WriteLine (solveDFS (initialState, 0, Right, 0))



let x0 = ('a',2)
let x1 = ('b',2)
let x2 = ('c',3)
let x3 = ('d',2)
let x4 = ('e',2)
let x5 = ('f',1)
let x6 = ('g',2)
let x7 = ('h',2)
let x8 = ('i',2)
let x9 = ('j',2)
let x10 = ('k',3)
let x11 = ('l',3)

let brickInfo = [|x0;x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6;x7;x8;x9;x10;x11|]
let horizontalBricks = [|[|4|];[|7|];[|6|];[|0|];[|2|];[|1|]|]
let verticalBricks = [|[|3|];[||];[|5|];[|10|];[|8;9|];[|11|]|]
let [<Literal>] rowNum = 6
let [<Literal>] columnNum = 6

let p0 = (3,0)
let p1 = (5,0)
let p2 = (4,0)
let p3 = (1,0)
let p4 = (0,0)
let p5 = (0,2)
let p6 = (2,2)
let p7 = (1,3)
let p8 = (2,4)
let p9 = (4,4)
let p10 = (3,3)
let p11 = (1,5)


let initialState = [|p0;p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11|]

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew ()

    test (initialState, brickInfo, horizontalBricks, verticalBricks, rowNum, columnNum)
    |> ignore

    sw.Stop()

    Console.WriteLine sw.Elapsed
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: A few more small tweaks: `checkBoth` could be shortened to `current > target || current + length - 1 < target` and `isDuplicated` to `not (set.Add(currentState))`.

Comment: Is there any way to simplify `generateUp generateLeft ...` as they take the majority of coding space

Comment: @colinfang as for points #1 and #4 in your comments -- can you name some specific books? I'm 99.9% certain I'm correct there, so I'm curious to know where you read that.

Comment: No, there's not much you could do with them.